# Display same class only once with jquery

Tags: jquery, class

How i can make in this JS to display only once same class?

In the example below you can see 3 times `class="33"` but i need to display only once div with same class...

**JS**

```
function callMeOften()
{
     $.ajax({
        method: 'get',
        url : '1.php',
        dataType : 'text',
        success: function (text) {
            $('#updateMe').html(text)  ;
        }
    });
}
var holdTheInterval = setInterval(callMeOften, 500000);
$(".<? echo $userRank['userID'] ?>").appendTo("#statMSG1");
});
```

**html**

```
<div id="33" class="33">Test</div>
<div id="33" class="33">Test</div>
<div id="45" class="45">Test2</div>
<div id="33" class="33">Test</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add your server-response to the DOM you can just select the first element with the `33` class and only add it:

```
$("#updateMe").html($(text).filter(".33").eq(0));​
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BsVFj/

Notice the use of `.filter({selector})` to return only element(s) in the current set that match the selector. Since your elements are siblings that have no parent you have to use `.filter()` to narrow then down, `.find()` only looks in descendant elements.

Some documentation for ya:

- `.filter()`: http://api.jquery.com/filter
- `.eq()`: http://api.jquery.com/eq